# how to set formatting of all textbox in asp.net website with css, without set cssclass property of each textbox

Tags: asp.net, css, web-applications, formatting

I am working on Asp.Net web site.
I want to set Font, color and background color of all textbox in my website.
i want to do it with css.

But i dont want to assign "cssclass" property of each textbox.

and as textbox i want to set formatting in RequiredFieldValidator.

is it possible to set it globally in Asp.Net with CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this in your css file

```
input[type=text]
{
  background-color:black;
  font-family:Callibri;
  color:white;
}
```

this style will be applied on every textbox

Comment: what would be for RequiredFieldValidator ??

Comment: @haider for required validator you have to use class